# Making recurring requests to a web service using Task.Run

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I am practicing with using Tasks and I put something together but am unsure if I used it properly.  I read through Stephen Cleary's blog and it seems that it is okay but at the same time I do some things that seem like there is a better way.  So what my program does is it has a start button and a stop button. When you press the start button it will start doing recurring requests to a webservice. At that time the start button is disabled and the stop button is enabled. When the requests finish up, I want the start button to be re-enabled and the stop button to become disabled.

This is what I have in my Form:

```
private async void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      ...
      ...
      ...
            btnSend.Enabled = false;
            btnStop.Enabled = true;

            cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

            try
            {
                // wait for the task to finish before continuing to enable the buttons 
                task t = requestThread.Execute(cts.Token);
                await t;
            }
            catch (Exception eRun)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(eRun.Message, "Application Error");
            }
            finally
            {
                cts.Dispose();
            }

            // re-enable btnSend
            btnSend.Enabled = true;
            btnStop.Enabled = false;
```

And then the Execute method:

```
public async Task Execute(CancelationToken ct) 
    {
        UI.Log("-------------------------------------------------");
        UI.Log("Starting Test Execution");

        if (Recurring)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= NumberOfRequests; i++)
            {
                if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                    return;
                UI.Log(string.Format("Attempting {0} of {1}", i, numberOfRequests));
                await SendRequest(ct);
                if (NumberOfRequests > 1 && i != numberOfRequests)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        await Task.Delay(timeInterval * 1000, ct);
                    }
                    catch (TaskCanceledException e)
                    {
                        // do nothing it's okay
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            await SendRequest(ct);
        }

        UI.Log("Test Execution Complete");
    }
```

I would really appreciate it if someone with some more Task experience can give me some pointers on whether this looks okay or I am breaking etiquette.

Edit: I have done some improvements with the help of a discussion from StackOverflow. Particularly, I removed the `Task.Run` since neither the `Execute` nor the `SendRequest` methods are CPU-bound. I changed my `request.GetResponse` to `await request.GetResponseAsync()` in `SendRequest`. This way I'm not wasting a thread from the thread pool for no reason.